# How can I parse a binary XML file (like AndroidManifest.xml) in c++?

Tags: android, c++, xml-parsing, apk, android-manifest

I want to parse AndroidManifest.xml in C++. Due to this file is a binary XML, I couldn't parse it with typical XML parsers in C++ like pugixml.
As I searched on the Internet, I found the [AAPT2](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/aapt2) tool for parsing AndroidManifest.xml, but I couldn't build the [AAPT2 repository](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/tree/master/tools/aapt2) in Visual Studio to take advantage of it in parsing AndroidManifest.xml ...

I need a piece of code that parses AndroidManifest.xml in C++.

This is a link to download a sample for [AndroidManifest.xml](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rQ9YYaa_-J335IC3PtWwzrU5R5lXtcOM/view).

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I solved the problem with the help of [AxmlDec (Android Binary XML Decoder)](https://github.com/ytsutano/axmldec) tool.